# Using IMPORTDATA() with objects from google bucket

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-bucket

Does the '=IMPORTDATA()' function within google sheets, work when using URLs from google buckets?

I can only seem to get external URLs from other sites (AWS, etc.) to load when using the function.

Comment: Can you share an example of it?

Comment: sure. i loaded this file to a public google bucket: [link](https://storage.cloud.google.com/mypublicbucket99/test2.txt)  ...you should be able to access and view it. When i use '=IMPORTDATA("https://storage.cloud.google.com/mypublicbucket99/test2.txt")' it doesn't work....it looks like rather than opening the link, the function loads the authentication website and not the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the `googleapis` endpoint instead:

`=IMPORTDATA("https://storage.googleapis.com/mypublicbucket99/test2.txt")`

*Reference*: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#typical

Comment: @Jescabekkas: fantastic! i didn't know this was required when using google storage. Is the same format, https://storage.googleapis.com/[Bucket_name]/[Object_Name] used for for non-public data?